# LaTeX Editor with proper Tree View

Tags: texstudio, texmaker, editors, forward-inverse-search

I used TeXnicCenter for years, and since it is not actively maintained, I have to find an alternative (under Windows).

My main concern for popular choices such as TeXstudio and TeXmaker is their improper structure view. I want a treeview that basically mirrors the table of contents of my book project at any time. But typically, as soon as I work with distributed TeX files for chapters using `input` or `include`, those editors get lost and show only the internal structure of the currently opened file. TeXnicCenter did a very good job, and currently, I switched to WinEdt which is doing this well also.

Are you aware of other editors that might be suitable for me?

Noteworthy, forward and inverse search in PDF (as it is provided by TeXnicCenter/SumatraPDF, WinEdt/SumatraPDF, TeXstudio, TeXmaker) is also appreciated.

Thanks for your recommendations.